# stitch multiple microscope images using python

Tags: python, images, opencv, photo-stitching

I'm trying to stitch a scan of a large area made using a microscope but I'm not having a whole lot of luck.
I started testing with 3 images extracted from a scanning video.
I stitched each 2 matching images but when I want to combine the 2 new composite images it looks very warped.
Does anyone know a decent way to stitch multiple images scanning a surface by changing the perspective but not the angle of view? I've only found ways that assume that the perspective remains constant and you are just rotating around that
[image]
[image]
[image]

Alternative to this problem: is it possible to align images using keypoints without warping?

edit: I've got it working now without any distortions but does anyone know a way to merge images while ignoring black? I want to get rid of these black lines beneath the image.
[image]

Edit: Problem solved.
[image]